# Como posso atribuir uma variável em uma tabela?

Tags: r

Essa tabela esta apenas em uma coluna ! 
Preciso atribuir a variável age(idade), para fazer a media, variância, ..., mas não consigo fazer isso pois estão na mesma coluna.

ID,"Name","Sex","Age","Height","Weight","Team","NOC","Games","Year","Season","City","Sport","Event","Medal"
1,"A Dijiang","M",24,180,80,"China","CHN","1992 Summer",1992,"Summer","Barcelona","Basketball","Basketball Men's Basketball",NA
2,"A Lamusi","M",23,170,60,"China","CHN","2012 Summer",2012,"Summer","London","Judo","Judo Men's Extra-Lightweight",NA
3,"Gunnar Nielsen Aaby","M",24,NA,NA,"Denmark","DEN","1920 Summer",1920,"Summer","Antwerpen","Football","Football Men's Football",NA
4,"Edgar Lindenau Aabye","M",34,NA,NA,"Denmark/Sweden","DEN","1900 Summer",1900,"Summer","Paris","Tug-Of-War","Tug-Of-War Men's Tug-Of-War","Gold"
5,"Christine Jacoba Aaftink","F",21,185,82,"Netherlands","NED","1988 Winter",1988,"Winter","Calgary","Speed Skating","Speed Skating Women's 500 metres",NA
5,"Christine Jacoba Aaftink","F",21,185,82,"Netherlands","NED","1988 Winter",1988,"Winter","Calgary","Speed Skating","Speed Skating Women's 1,000 metres",NA
5,"Christine Jacoba Aaftink","F",25,185,82,"Netherlands","NED","1992 Winter",1992,"Winter","Albertville","Speed Skating","Speed Skating Women's 500 metres",NA
5,"Christine Jacoba Aaftink","F",25,185,82,"Netherlands","NED","1992 Winter",1992,"Winter","Albertville","Speed Skating","Speed Skating Women's 1,000 metres",NA
5,"Christine Jacoba Aaftink","F",27,185,82,"Netherlands","NED","1994 Winter",1994,"Winter","Lillehammer","Speed Skating","Speed Skating Women's 500 metres",NA
5,"Christine Jacoba Aaftink","F",27,185,82,"Netherlands","NED","1994 Winter",1994,"Winter","Lillehammer","Speed Skating","Speed Skating Women's 1,000 metres",NA
6,"Per Knut Aaland","M",31,188,75,"United States","USA","1992 Winter",1992,"Winter","Albertville","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 10 kilometres",NA
6,"Per Knut Aaland","M",31,188,75,"United States","USA","1992 Winter",1992,"Winter","Albertville","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 50 kilometres",NA
6,"Per Knut Aaland","M",31,188,75,"United States","USA","1992 Winter",1992,"Winter","Albertville","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 10/15 kilometres Pursuit",NA
6,"Per Knut Aaland","M",31,188,75,"United States","USA","1992 Winter",1992,"Winter","Albertville","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 4 x 10 kilometres Relay",NA
6,"Per Knut Aaland","M",33,188,75,"United States","USA","1994 Winter",1994,"Winter","Lillehammer","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 10 kilometres",NA
6,"Per Knut Aaland","M",33,188,75,"United States","USA","1994 Winter",1994,"Winter","Lillehammer","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 30 kilometres",NA
6,"Per Knut Aaland","M",33,188,75,"United States","USA","1994 Winter",1994,"Winter","Lillehammer","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 10/15 kilometres Pursuit",NA
6,"Per Knut Aaland","M",33,188,75,"United States","USA","1994 Winter",1994,"Winter","Lillehammer","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 4 x 10 kilometres Relay",NA
7,"John Aalberg","M",31,183,72,"United States","USA","1992 Winter",1992,"Winter","Albertville","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 10 kilometres",NA
7,"John Aalberg","M",31,183,72,"United States","USA","1992 Winter",1992,"Winter","Albertville","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 50 kilometres",NA
7,"John Aalberg","M",31,183,72,"United States","USA","1992 Winter",1992,"Winter","Albertville","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 10/15 kilometres Pursuit",NA
7,"John Aalberg","M",31,183,72,"United States","USA","1992 Winter",1992,"Winter","Albertville","Cross Country Skiing","Cross Country Skiing Men's 4 x 10 kilometres Relay",NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teus dados tem a forma de um arquivo separado por vírgulas (csv), mas com presença de aspas para os valores. Acredito que um simples `read.csv` não ira functionar (outras sugestões são bem-vindas).

Uma solução será copiar esses dados em um ficher `txt` e ler com um `read.table`.
Primeiramente vamos ler o ficheiro indicando a separação por espaço. Dessa maneira cada elemento conterá a linha inteira do data frame

```
# ler ficheiro (warning é devido a falta de estrutura do documento)
dados <- read.table('data.txt', sep = ' ')

# separar entre cabeçalho e dados
cab <- dados[1]
dados <- dados[-1]
```

Agora vamos seprar cada valor separado por vírgula com a função `strsplit()`

```
# separar cada elemento por vírgula
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 15))
for(i in 1:length(dados)) {
  df[i, ] <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(dados[, i]), ','))
}

# incluir cabeçalho
names(df) <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(cab[, 1]), ','))

# transformar variáveis
for(i in c(4, 5, 6, 10)) {
  df[, i] <- as.numeric(df[, i])
}
```